# How do Torontonians pronounce the name of their hometown?

Tags: pronunciation, canadian-english

Toronto - The capital and largest city of Ontario, Canada, in the southern part of the province on Lake Ontario.

- [tə-ˈrän-(ˌ)tō, -ˈrän-tə] — [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toronto)
- [tuh-ron-toh] — [Reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/toronto)
- [təˈrän(t)ō] — [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Toronto)

> Context: The 2012 Oscar winning movie “Argo”.   Decades ago, when the Iranian revolution was reaching a boiling point and the American embassy in Tehran was invaded, six Americans escaped and found shelter at  the Canadian ambassy. To get out of Iran more or less safely they received new identities as Canadian teachers.   At this point, they were told they would be asked where they came from, at the airport, and **were warned that Torontonians don’t pronounce the name of their city the same way most English speaking people do.**

I've searched several dictionaries and have only found the usual pronunciation.

Comment: Did you notice the pronunciation you listed: [təˈrän(t)ō]? This (t) means the second 't' is ***optional***, and listening to [forvo.com](http://www.forvo.com/word/toronto/), I believe many Torontonians leave it out.

Comment: @peter shor i bet you're right. this seems similar to *baltimore*, for which people who live in the area also elide the *t*.

Comment: @ermanen If you are really a Torontonian you should answer this question.

Comment: Toronto native here. We pronounce it Tor-on-toe. There is no silent t.

Comment: @robbmj "Tor-on-toe", like UK English? British was (and [may be still](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto#Demographics)) the largest ethnicity in Toronto.

Comment: I always thought the gentilic for a Toronto denizen was *Torontan* not *Torontonian*, which is awfully long.  At least the first would shorten to tʃɻʷɑʔn̩

Comment: The real question is how would Iranians know the local pronunciation?

Comment: @JamesRyan Director Ben Affleck could tell you that.

Comment: @Centaurus: I'm not good at explaining pronunciation. You have to hear it from me :) There are already good answers. Most important part is, second t is silent. Forvo.com is a good start as Peter Shor mentioned. Though, people use "t-dot" as a nickname too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When I was living in Calgary, Alberta, in the early 1970s, a student fresh from Toronto (where she had grown up) enrolled in our high school—and I would swear that she pronounced *Toronto* in two syllables: ˈträn-ə.

Admittedly (1) the pronunciation may have changed or (2) our transfer student may have had an idiosyncratic pronunciation or (3) even though I would swear to the accuracy of the memory, I may not be remembering it correctly.

I do know that the nasal tone with which she pronounced *Toronto* was a source of great mirth to the chirpy native Calgarians.

Comment: That sounds basically like what I have always heard from Torontonians. Writing it _Tronna_ is quite common too (like Strylia for Australia, Oireland for Ireland, or various variations of Sef Efrica for South Africa).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *Strine* for 'Australia' is *Striya* (though locals write *Straya*), with no L, at least not one discernable to foreigners.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't know whether this is an Inland North dialect characteristic, or whether it’s just some ubiquitous urge found everywhere (English is spoken (stress-timed)) to get everything down to as few syllables as one can get away with, but you sure do hear it a lot in the Great Lakes region. *Milwaukee* is Mwawkee; *Wisconsin* is Sconsun; *Buffalo* is *Buflow*; *Chicago* is Shkawgow; *Sault Sainte Marie* is odd, and *Flint* is — well, flint. :) On the other hand, a native Minnesotan will ***not*** flap that *-t-*, confounding other North Americans with its Scandihoovian vestiges.

Comment: @Glen_b Right you are!

Comment: I have been to Toronto and have lots of family there. They all say Trawno.

Comment: Either Tronna or Toronna. Americans are easily spotted with the -toe thing.

Answer (score 11):

[Peter Shor's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207431/how-do-torontonians-pronounce-the-name-of-their-hometown#comment440046_207431) is right: that second 't' is silent, in the stereotypical accent, so it's something like, "te-rah-na" ... eh?

Also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto) gives `/ˈtrɒnoʊ/` so the first vowel, too, is elided.

I'm not sure whether the first vowel is there or not. I think it's something like /tɨˈrɒnoʊ/ with a reduced first vowel and more stress on the 'R' than on the initial 'T', but who knows.

As an aside: apart from that "Canadian" accent, 50% of the inhabitants of Toronto were born outside Canada. So actual "Torontonians" are also likely to pronounce it with a Ukrainian accent, or with a Chinese accent, or etc.

Comment: Just like the capital of Albania (-:

Comment: Yes about [like that](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/En-us-Tirana.ogg) but without the "I" between the "T" and the "R".

Comment: I think you mean that the first (not the first two) syllable is elided. If the first two were elided, you'd end up with /trna/ or something like that…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks, you're right. I thought "two syllables elided" meant, "squished together into one syllable".

Comment: Then they would be contracted (and that's usually reserved for when two adjacent vowels contract into one, as when _liar_ becomes monosyllabic /la:r/ in some US dialects). :-)

Comment: Good point about non-uniform pronunciation among immigrants. In [Olivia Chow's speech](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWeDEEF_neo&t=1m40s) (skip to 1m40s), the second `/t/` is clearly audible. ([Olivia Chow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivia_Chow), who was born in Hong Kong, is a Member of Parliament and was a mayoral candidate.)

Comment: I am from Toronto, and I and most people I know pronounce it [tə-ˈränō] (second t silent, long o at the end, but not with an elided first vowel). This answer is a good one.

Comment: I am from Ottawa; I lived in Toronto for 25 years until recently.

Answer (score 3):

'Trawna' if we're both from there, 'Trawn-toe' if we're speaking to someone who isn't from there.

Answer (score 1):

Your [merriam-webster link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toronto) shows two pronunciations: [tə-ˈrän-(ˌ)tō] and [tə-ˈrän-tə].  The second of those, ending with a [short vowel](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/pron/sounds/vowel_short_5.shtml), more or less agrees with the pronunciation I was told by a Torontonian about nine years ago.  Due to the lapse of time, I don't remember for certain if he slightly elided the second *t* – ie, somewhat like [tə-ˈrän-ə] instead of [tə-ˈrän-tə] – but I think he might have.